# How can I use sudo to check if a file exists?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want to check if a file exists like so

`[ -f /path/to/file/ ]`

However I am running this command as a regular user and the file is owned by root. How can I use sudo to accomplish this.

`sudo [ -f /path/to/file/ ]`   does not work.

Comment: It does work on my system. What are the symptoms ? Are you sure you want to use -f, not -e ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're describing should work fine - as long as you're using absolute paths, and `-f` ("File exists and is a regular file") is really the test you want to perform.

I see a trailing `/` in what you posted in your question - Are you testing for a directory? That should be `-d`, or simply `-e` ("Something exists with that name - regardless of type")

Also note that unless something along the way is not readable `test` (`[`) should be able to tell you if a file owned by root exists or not (e.g. `[ -f /root/.ssh/known_hosts ]` will probably fail, because the /root/.ssh directory isn't (or at least *shouldn't be*) readable by a normal user.  `[ -f /etc/crontab ]` should succeed).

Comment: There is a possible problem: if the `sudo` command fails (bad password, not allowed in /etc/sudoers, etc), it'll give the same result as if the file didn't exist.

Comment: @Gordon - true: My answer is predicated on the `sudo` portion working :)

Answer (score 27):

```
if sudo test -f "/path/to/file"; then
    echo "FILE EXISTS"
else
    echo "FILE DOESN'T EXIST"
fi
```

[test man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)

To complete things, on the opposite side, if you want to check from root if a file or directory is readable for a certain user you can use

```
if sudo -u username test -f "/path/to/file"; then
    echo "FILE EXISTS"
else
    echo "FILE DOESN'T EXIST"
fi
```

Comment: Luca Borrione's answer worked perfectly for me. I needed to test existence of files that were deep inside directories readable only by root.

Comment: How might you test for the file missing if not using else?  how might you use ! to test?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the other answers, distinguishing between the test or sudo authentication failing could be done by first running `sudo true`. Most sudo implementations I know of won't require re-authentication within a short period.

For example:

```
if sudo true; then
    if sudo test -f "/path/to/file"; then
        echo "FILE EXISTS"
    else
        echo "FILE DOESN'T EXIST"
    fi
else
    echo "SUDO AUTHENTICATION FAILED"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to through this out there since its how I tend to do it

if [ $(sudo ls /etc/ | grep -ic '^wsl.conf$') -gt 0  ]; then
...
fi

I like that way as its a bit explicit and I find it should 100% work. I have had issues where if I didn't have the right permissions just using -f always failed

Comment: somehow other solutiosn did not work and just this one works for me

Comment: glad the post helped someone